# How to solve the xor problem with neural network

Tags: neural-networks

As this [playground](http://playground.tensorflow.org/#activation=relu&batchSize=30&dataset=xor&regDataset=reg-plane&learningRate=0.03&regularizationRate=0&noise=15&networkShape=4&seed=0.46171&showTestData=false&discretize=false&percTrainData=50&x=true&y=true&xTimesY=false&xSquared=false&ySquared=false&cosX=false&sinX=false&cosY=false&sinY=false&collectStats=false&problem=classification&initZero=false&hideText=false) show after you click [this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlsRQ.png), just [four levels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Yk5H.png) can solve the xor problem. So I try to simulate it in *Mathematica*

### Generate test points

```
    disk1 = Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {0, Pi/2}];
    disk2 = Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {Pi/2, Pi}];
    disk3 = Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {Pi, 3 Pi/2}];
    disk4 = Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {3 Pi/2, 2 Pi}];
    pts = RandomPoint[#, RandomInteger[{30, 40}]] & /@ {disk1, disk2, 
    disk3, disk4};
    Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], {Red, Point[Catenate[pts[[{1, 3}]]]], Blue,
    Point[Catenate[pts[[{2, 4}]]]]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Training the network

```
data = Flatten[
   Thread /@ {Catenate[pts[[{1, 3}]]] -> 1, 
     Catenate[pts[[{2, 4}]]] -> 0}];
net = NetChain[{4, Ramp, 2, Ramp, 
    SoftmaxLayer["Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {0, 1}}]]}, 
   "Input" -> 2];
trainednet = 
 NetTrain[net, data, ValidationSet -> Scaled[.2], 
  TargetDevice -> "GPU"]
```

### Show the trained result

```
ContourPlot[trainednet[{x, y}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Red, Point[Catenate[pts[[{1, 3}]]]], 
   Blue, Point[Catenate[pts[[{2, 4}]]]]}]
```

[image]

We get a good result as the above image, but actually,we often get a frustrated result like following
[image]

I'm confused, because the playground always converge well. Why I use same network layer but cannot get same good result? How to improve it?

Comment: Without testing anything: The `Ramp` before the `SoftmaxLayer` looks suspicious

Comment: @nikie [Then](https://i.stack.imgur.com/on90h.png). :) And as my textbook,that is not a problem.

Comment: @nikie It will be [better a little indeed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpE3J.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

(Sidenote: It's annoying if you change the question so the answer you got doesn't work anymore...)

I think this is normal for ReLU activation. If all channels in the middle layer are 0 in one quadrant at initialization, the network will never learn in that quadrant, because the gradient is 0. It happens in the "playground", too. (Less frequently though - maybe they have a different initialization strategy.)

> How to improve it?

Either use more channels, or use an activation function that has a nonzero gradient everywhere (like Tanh)

Comment: If you mean I change the number from 10 to 4, because that is a typo. I want to simulate [playground](http://playground.tensorflow.org/#activation=relu&batchSize=30&dataset=xor&regDataset=reg-plane&learningRate=0.03&regularizationRate=0&noise=15&networkShape=4&seed=0.46171&showTestData=false&discretize=false&percTrainData=50&x=true&y=true&xTimesY=false&xSquared=false&ySquared=false&cosX=false&sinX=false&cosY=false&sinY=false&collectStats=false&problem=classification&initZero=false&hideText=false) and it just need 4 levels.